# Slide transition in new Android L API

Tags: android, slide, transition, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying new Android L API in particular transitions. The best experience I have with "Fade" but "Slide.RIGHT" behaves really weird…  When screen fly in it brings firstly screen title at the bottom, then title jump to the top of the screen and rest of the screen is appear…

I did not use custom transition, just basic one. Screen I use for testing has just couple of TextView, EditText and button. But even if I change Google ActivitySceneTransitionBasicSample from custom transition to basic Slide.RIGHT  it behave the same strange way…

Is somebody managed to implement nice Slide transition? In my case I need to Slide completely different screens. There are no elements I can share.

My code is:

First Activity:

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
    Slide transitionEnter = new Slide();
    transitionEnter.setSlideEdge(Gravity.RIGHT);
    transitionEnter.setDuration(1000);
    Window currentW = getWindow();
    currentW.setEnterTransition(transitionEnter);
    currentW.setExitTransition(transitionEnter);

    getWindow().setAllowEnterTransitionOverlap(true);
    getWindow().setAllowExitTransitionOverlap(true);

    setContentView(R.layout.slide_test_view);
    }
    public void buttonLAction(View view){
        Utils.startActivity(this, SecondSlideTestActivity.class);
    }
```

Second Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
    Slide transitionEnter = new Slide();
    transitionEnter.setSlideEdge(Gravity.RIGHT);
    transitionEnter.setDuration(1000);
    Window currentW = getWindow();
    currentW.setEnterTransition(transitionEnter);
    currentW.setExitTransition(transitionEnter);

    getWindow().setAllowEnterTransitionOverlap(true);
    getWindow().setAllowExitTransitionOverlap(true);

    setContentView(R.layout.second_slide_test_view);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a small suggestion, doesn't make it perfect but looks better in my opinion:

Use different edges for enter and exit transition, e.g.:

```
transitionEnter.setSlideEdge(Gravity.RIGHT);
transitionExit.setSlideEdge(Gravity.LEFT);
```

I did that and for me it looks kinda okay then. Hope this helps!